# Scraping the url with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping

I want to get data from other url which is product info. I want to scrape all of this data for this attribute:

```
$('[data-b-for-cart]').attr('data-b-for-cart');
```

And want to export that to csv file.

Not sure hows this should be done any resource would be helpful.

I think I should use the jquery $.get is that right ?

Comment: "to scv file" do you mean csv ?

Comment: yes sorry for the typo

Answer (score 1):

you can try ajax within jquery to scrape. It is not that difficult

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  baseUrl = "http://www.somedomain.com/";
  $.ajax({
    url: baseUrl,
    type: "get",
    dataType: "",
    success: function(data) {
      //do something with data and save as csv file
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Given the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) it is actually ***very*** difficult, if not impossible, to perform scraping in JS reliably.

Comment: maybe use a lib (http://papaparse.com/#unparse) for csv conversion rather than rolling your own function : csv can be tricky

Comment: @AliceOualouest definately JavaScript isn't intended for doing such operations and its limitations should be exploited using other libraries.

Comment: @DanyalImran yeah you could use other stuff, but i just need that quick with jQuery. I have few question: for dataType do I put it JSON and convert it to CSV ? also  how to save as csv file maybe you know any resource? and where should I pass this $('[data-b-for-cart]').attr('data-b-for-cart'); as I only need info from this attribute.